# Finding singular solutions to a first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we have a differential equation of the type:
$$F(x,y,y')=0$$ And it's solutions:
$$\phi(x,y,C)=0$$
Then there are two ways to find singular solutions (if there are any).

The first one is straight forward. The singular solution has to obey $\phi=0$ and if we change the constant $C$ (that is if we jump between the general solutions) then $\phi$ has to stay constant. So we get the system of equations that will give us the singular solution(s):
$$
\phi(x,y,C) = 0
$$
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial C} = 0$$
For the second method we can use is the following system:
$$F(x,y,y')=0$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=0$$ And I don't understand it. Can you derive why it is true or at least share what is the intuition behind the last two equations?